# AjaxControlToolkit MaskedEditExtender issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, .net-3.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Why does my `MaskedEditExtender` which looks like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="extenderPhone" runat="server" 
MessageValidatorTip="false" Mask="+112 99 999-99-99" TargetControlID="tbb"
ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" MaskType="None" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false"
AcceptNegative="None" AutoComplete="false" />
```

not work?

When I set focus on other control, and then set focus on the text box with the extender, the mask on this textbox is duplicating.  Like this:

```
+112 __ ___-__-__

+112 11 2__-__-__

+112 11 211-2_-__

+112 11 211-21-12
```

Comment: You don't have any other javascript on the page that would affect this, right?  Does this only occur in a particular browser?  Also, I don't see that "`ClearMaskOnLostFocus`" property on the [documentation page](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx)

Comment: I do not have any other scripts on my page. This issue occurs on IE and FF (did not test others).